# charts won't draw with extjs 3.4

Tags: extjs, charts, extjs4, extjs3

A simple problem, really simple code, i just copy/paste the code example, on my local project of course, but no charts drawing ... i really don't understand what's happening, i change in doubt url of the swf on my local folder, same problem, please help !

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Charts v1.0</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ext-all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ext-base-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    Ext.onReady(function(){

         // extra extra simple
        Ext.chart.Chart.CHART_URL = 'images/charts.swf';

         var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
            fields:['name', 'visits', 'views'],
        data: [
            {name:'Jul 07', visits: 245000, views: 3000000},
            {name:'Aug 07', visits: 240000, views: 3500000},
            {name:'Sep 07', visits: 355000, views: 4000000},
            {name:'Oct 07', visits: 375000, views: 4200000},
            {name:'Nov 07', visits: 490000, views: 4500000},
            {name:'Dec 07', visits: 495000, views: 5800000},
            {name:'Jan 08', visits: 520000, views: 6000000},
            {name:'Feb 08', visits: 620000, views: 7500000}
        ]
        });

// extra extra simple
new Ext.Panel({
    title: 'ExtJS.com Visits Trend, 2007/2008 (No styling)',
    renderTo: 'container',
    width:500,
    height:300,
    layout:'fit',
    items: {
        xtype: 'linechart',
        store: store,
        xField: 'name',
        yField: 'visits',
        listeners: {
            itemclick: function(o){
                var rec = store.getAt(o.index);
                Ext.example.msg('Item Selected', 'You chose {0}.', rec.get('name'));
            }
        }
    }
});
});

</script>
<body style="padding: 50px;"><div id='container'></div></body>
 </html>
```

No network problem, all needed ressources are correctly loaded .. also tried with no def of the url, in this case extjs get the swf on yahooui cdn, same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot run it locally without a webserver, that's why it fails. Setup up a local webserver an it should work.

Comment: I actually use apache, could somone copy/paste this code, and run it locally

Comment: Hay I actually copied the code given by you and kept in my IIS (c://inetpub/wwwroot/extjs3.4/examples) and changed the references to files and images and it worked well for me !
Check in fidler anything with 404 error.

In short same code is working for me.

Comment: This is an official issue ! The swf present in the yahoo libs is no longer working with extjs3.4, u have to download it yourself on the official example of extjs... this working great when placing the swf of the package ;)