# ExtJS 3.2 pie chart not rendering in IE 8

Tags: extjs, internet-explorer-8, charts, pie-chart

I have create a pie-chart using ExtJS 3.2, but it is not rendering in Internet Explorer 8, can anyone suggest me what is the  problem. Below is my code for pie-chart:

```
function customPieChart(dataStore) {
    var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        fields: ['responseType', 'total'],
        data:  dataStore
    });


    var pan =  new Ext.Panel({
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        title: 'Non Acceptable to Acceptable Chart',
        items: {
            store: store,
            xtype: 'piechart',
            dataField: 'total',
            categoryField: 'responseType',
            extraStyle:
            {
                legend:
                {
                    display: 'bottom',
                    padding: 5,
                    font:
                    {
                        family: 'Tahoma',
                        size: 13
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
     var win = new Ext.Window({ items: pan, layout: 'fit', width: 500, height: 300}).show();    
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExtJS 3 uses Flash to render the charts. So the first thing to check is to make sure that Flash is installed and working in your Internet Explorer 8.

You can also look at this answer that can be relevant if you try to run it locally: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14619088/579697